# Regex Quantifier Which Number of Occurrence Gets Tested First?

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm completely new to regex and recently started learning it. Here's a part of my test string from which I'd like to find matches.

```
24 bit:
Black #000000
12 bit:
Black #000
```

My question is the following. When I use regex expression `#(\w{1,2})`, the group matches `00` in both 24-bit Black and 12-bit Black. However when I use regex `#(\w{1,2})\1\1`, the group matches `00` in 24-bit Black but `0` in 12-bit Black. Although I'm not familiar with how regex works, I'm curious what's the logic behind this. When I use curly braces quantifier `{a,b}` to indicate `a <= (# occurrences) <= b`, for the numbers `a, a+1,...,b`, which one is used to check for matching first? For example, with `#(\w{1,2})` it seems 2 occurrences is used first. But after adding `\1\1`, it seems to me somehow regex was able to see that using 1 occurrence instead of 2 would result in matching 12-bit Black?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I had more of these RGB color codes and I wanted to match colors whose R == G == B

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `#(\w{1,2})\1\1` does the job but that question came to my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `#(\w{1,2})\1\1` can match `#000000` and `#000` because `\w{1,2}` can backtrack 1 position to fit in the matches for the backreferences `\1\1`

You make the pattern a bit more specific

```
#([0-9a-fA-F]{1,2})\1\1
```

Or if there should be no surrounding non whitespace characters:

```
(?<!\S)#([0-9a-fA-F]{1,2})\1\1(?!\S)
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/AyXWW5/1).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the concept of backtracking at all.